# ASP.NET Databound values behind by 1 postback

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, select, gridview, postback

I have a `GridView` filled with databound content. Each row is selectable. When clicking the row (`selectedindexchanged`) I then filter my second gridview with the data key of the first one (the data key of `GridView1` acts as a filter criteria for `GridView2`, I change the `FilterExpression` for `GridView2` to match the data key of `GridView1`). This works, as `GridView2` appears to be filtered correctly corresponding to the selected row. However, something strange happens upon selecting a row.

Selecting the row filters the second gridview correctly, however the values I get back from the second gridview (by doing `GridView2.Rows[0].Cell(2).Text`) always lag one postback behind for only two columns... And it only happens once I've already selected a row twice! It's weird.

So for example if I select the first row in `GridView1`. This filters my second GridView correctly, giving me a value of 1. So `GridView2.Rows[0].Cell(2).Text = 1`. Then if I click the second row in GridView 1, once again GridView 2 filters correctly, showing the right information, but `GridView2.Rows[0].Cell(2).Text` will still give me 1 instead of lets say 5. Then if I select the third row in GridView1, GridView 2 filters no problem, and `GridView2.Rows[0].Cell(2).Text` will give me 5. And yet another column contained in the same grid will change correctly. Only two columns are lagging 1 postback behind.

I have been working on this for months on-and-off and nothing has worked. I have no way of really toubleshooting this... any ideas?

EDIT: The code that occurs during the `indexchanged` event per request:

```
Protected Sub GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles GridView1.SelectedIndexChanged
    Dim rowId As Integer = CInt(GridView1.DataKeys(GridView1.SelectedIndex).Value)
    SqlDataSource6.FilterExpression = ""
    SqlDataSource6.FilterExpression = "InquiryID = " & rowId
    GridView2.Visible = True
    TextBox2.Text = GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells(2).Text
    DropDownList2.SelectedValue = GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells(3).Text
    DropDownList3.SelectedValue = GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells(4).Text
    DropDownList4.SelectedValue = GridView2.Rows(0).Cells(1).Text


End Sub
```

So what's happening there is, I get the RowID of the selected row in GridView1, use it to filter GridView2, then I set all the form control values in the page to match the ones in the grid. The postbacks that are one value behind are `DropDownList2` and `DropDownList4`. `DropDownList3`'s values are completely fine.

Comment: This issue is still occurring.

Comment: Issue is still occurring, have not been able to find a solution yet.

Comment: posting some more complete code would help. My gut feeling is is a strangeness either in view state, or in the order that events are firing when a postback occurs.

Comment: @Jeremy I've added the code in question

Comment: Do you have any column in your GridView1 with visible property set to 'False'?

Comment: @AmneshGoel no, I only have 4 columns, the first being the data key. the data key is readonly and insertvisible is set to false, but those should not be an issue.